# Using a CQ parsys from the sidekick only displays on refresh

Tags: aem

I created a component to be used from the sidekick that contains 2 parsys'. However, when that component is dragged onto the page, said parsys' do not display until the page is refreshed.

```
<div>   
<h3 class="subheading">
    <span class="toggle"></span><c:out escapeXml='false' value='${heading}' default='- Element heading here -'/>
</h3>
<div class="accordion-content" data-expanded="${openElement}">

<ol>
  <cq:include path="numbered" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"/>
</ol>

<cq:include path="nonumbered" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"/>

</div>
```

Is there a reason why this would be happening?

Comment: Have you tried another browser? We had similar behaviour on some of our components, when people used Internet Explorer 8 while it would work with other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to checking if this is a browser-specific issue, you might also try `cq:EditConfig` (more information [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html), especially the section **CQ:LISTENERS**).

In your case, adding the node property `afterinsert` to the config-node with the value `REFRESH_PAGE` might do the trick for you.